# Bash script, error "Arg list too long"

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ubuntu, arguments

I need to run a bash script in a `.lua` file:

```
os.execute ("/path/to/file.sh")
```

file.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
route add 149.36.98.78 reject
```

The permissions for file.sh is `[-rwxr-x---]    root    www-data`

I'm getting the error "Arg list too long", if i put the bash code directly in the lua i get the same error:

```
os.execute ("route add 149.36.98.78 reject")
```

So it think that it's because the entire bash code is being executed inside quote marks, reference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11475221/10286151

This is the consts from my limits.h:

```
#ifndef _LINUX_LIMITS_H
#define _LINUX_LIMITS_H

#define NR_OPEN         1024

#define NGROUPS_MAX    65536    /* supplemental group IDs are available */
#define ARG_MAX       131072    /* # bytes of args + environ for exec() */
#define LINK_MAX         127    /* # links a file may have */
#define MAX_CANON        255    /* size of the canonical input queue */
#define MAX_INPUT        255    /* size of the type-ahead buffer */
#define NAME_MAX         255    /* # chars in a file name */
#define PATH_MAX        4096    /* # chars in a path name including nul */
#define PIPE_BUF        4096    /* # bytes in atomic write to a pipe */
#define XATTR_NAME_MAX   255    /* # chars in an extended attribute name */
#define XATTR_SIZE_MAX 65536    /* size of an extended attribute value (64k) */
#define XATTR_LIST_MAX 65536    /* size of extended attribute namelist (64k) */

#define RTSIG_MAX     32

#endif
```

How can i fix it? I tried to change the `ARG_MAX` to:

```
ARG_MAX       29107299
```

But it did not changed anything. I use Ubuntu 16.

When i searched about this i realized that this problem is because of the `ARG_MAX`, and what defines `ARG_MAX` is the file `/usr/include/linux/limits.h`, but i'm not sure because in the file `limits.h` my `ARG_MAX` is `131072`, but when i do `getconf ARG_MAX` i get `2621440`

Comment: What is `route` on your system? (what does `type route` say). As to modifying `limits.h`, you shouldn't do that, ever -- it will either have no effect whatsoever or badly break the C programs you compile them from source.

Comment: I did `type route` and it shows `route is /sbin/route`. You said that i should not modify the `limits.h` and it could breal C programs, it does not make permant damage, right? I undoed the modifications, rebooted, and the system is working fine. Althought i still have the problem with the "Arg list too long".

Comment: Are you certain it's actually _this_ command that generates the error?

Comment: @Kusalananda about the code yes i'm sure, because i only execute this command https://pastebin.com/raw/U4p9SvDG I tried to execute simple commands like `echo 'abc'` and it worked, so i think that the problem is really the "Arg list too long"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [list of errors](https://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) you've referenced in [your PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/raw/U4p9SvDG) is misleading you.

The error you're receiving is number 7, but this is a program exit code and almost certainly not a system error code. They are completely unrelated.

I believe that the actual problem is simply that you are trying to add the same rejection route twice:

```
# route add 152.48.25.29 reject; echo SS=$?
SS=0
# route add 152.48.25.29 reject; echo SS=$?
SIOCADDRT: File exists
SS=7
```

You would also get the same exit code from `route` if you tried to delete a non-existent route:

```
# route delete 152.48.25.29 reject; echo SS=$?
SS=0
# route delete 152.48.25.29 reject; echo SS=$?
SIOCDELRT: No such process
SS=7
```

To fix the problem you need to manage your wrapper. You can either test for a rejection route before trying to add it, or simply discard the error return. This example favours the second (simplistic) approach, but you may need to take the other option:

```
#!/bin/bash
route add 152.48.25.29 reject 2>/dev/null
exit 0
```

(You do know how to pass and reference parameters to a script using `"$1"` and friends, rather than embedding IP addresses verbatim, don't you?)

Comment: After i run `route add 152.48.25.29 reject; echo SS=$?` with a user that has no root privileges i got this output: `SIOCDELRT: Permission denied SS=7`, so i realied that the problem was because the `file.sh` was not being executed with `sudo`, and i thought i was executing `file.sh` as root (which was not).

Comment: After searching a while i found this answear that solved this problem https://askubuntu.com/a/153406/928635 and this is how my `sudoers` is now: https://pastebin.com/raw/PU77L1CT and i gave `500 [-r-x------]` permision to the folder and file.sh. Do you think it's safe? I saw some people saying that this method is not that good, but i don't know about my case.

Comment: The list of errors i was following was indded not giving me the correct information, and of couse my code was not being debugged correctly, It was only logging the exit code.